# Blazor server-side when refresh results in an AccessDenied error

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I use ASP.NET Core 8 Blazor server app with MVC, my problem is when I refresh my page with an authorize attribute, I get an http 403 error.

If I go back or rewrite the url, everything is fine.

I change default cookie and use JWT, but I still have this bug

Comment: 403 means unauthorized, pls share the authentication and authorization mechanism in Program.cs or a minimal reproducible sample.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

problem is i have attribute In Root Folder Of My AdminPanel and one in Child Folder for Example
Root: `@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, System")]`
Child: `@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "Branch")]`

I just Change my

```
@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "Branch")]
```

to

```
@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, System, Branch")]
```